# Is "then" considered as informal in a technical report?

Tags: formality

It is correct to use "then" in a formal sentence?

Here is an example sentence:

"In case that a cylinder is not at end position **then** the operator has to move manually the cylinder in order to meet this prerequisite"

Comment: This is effectively proofreading, so ***If** a cylinder is not at **the/an** end position then the operator has to move it manually*. All the rest is clumsy / ungrammatical / unnecessary verbiage. The word ***then*** is also unnecessary, but it's perfectly valid. No-one is likely to think any the less of the writer's competence, whether it's present or not.

Comment: As far as I know, using _then_ as the counterpart to _if_ in a sentence effectively structured as "If ... then ..." doesn't raise issues of insufficient formality. Indeed, if the implied "If ... then ..." structure is clear enough (as it is in this sentence), you may choose to omit the _then_ on grounds of its being unnecessary, not on grounds of its being "informal."

Comment: Whoever told you to avoid *then*? Perhaps you or they are misinterpreting other writing advice— not to repeat *then* in front of multiple sentences in a row, or to be careful about using *then* when you mean *than*, for example. All you need to do is *read* a few technical reports and you will certainly encounter *then* far more often than *ain't* or *got*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable if it's preceded by "if." Like this:

> **If** the cylinder is not at end position **then** the operator needs to move it manually.

Without "if," your "then" just wouldn't work:

> Should the cylinder be anywhere other than the end position, the operator must move it manually.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer seems to be saying ***then*** doesn't work in constructions like [***Should** that happen **then** we will do something*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22should+that+happen+then%22). I disagree.